# Can google map javascript API and map tiles be cached?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to develop a mobile app with Google map javascript API, and it needs to support offline mode, so users can view map without internet connected. 
So is it possible to cache google map javascript API(.js file) and map data?
If so, would you please give me some advice ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terms of use (legal issues), not coding.

Answer (score 2):

> **No caching or storage**. You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store any Content to be used outside the Service, except that you may store limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation due to network latency (and not for the purpose of preventing Google from accurately tracking usage), and only if such storage:

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_5

Comment: Thank you. I have read it before,  but I dont really understand it. I 'd better consult the lawyers.